# Implementing unit of work and service in WPF (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, service, unit-of-work

Which is more effective when you create an application (like student management system)?

- using DbContext directly to view models
- using the unit of work pattern with repositories and services

I am using `WPF` with `MVVM` pattern and `Entity Framework 6.0`.

Unit of work pattern reference: [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/repository-and-unitofwork-pattern-part-2/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to you use unit of work pattern with repositories and services. Well , its gives you separation of project.
I.e.

> 1. Data Access Layer (contains EF LINQ queries, models and datacontext , unitofwork)
> 2. Service Layer (Business and domain Logic)
> 3. Wpf Layer (UI part which talks to service layer only)
> 4. Test Layer (for unit testing…etc)

Advantage:
 you can easily avoid duplication of code.(Use generic repository for crud).
 You can easily change database in future (Change in just one layer)
Much more...

Comment: What's the difference between a data access layer and a service layer?

Comment: In data access layer write code to interact with database(mssql / oracle etc) . In service define Business constraint , logic , execption handling etc